# Unable to scroll on page using listview inside gridview

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I'm trying to develop a dashboard page, with 4 gridviews in a row and 2 gridviews in another row(image below). I'm trying to make the page scrollable and make it look like the image shown below:

[image: Image to show what i'm trying to build]

I have developed the layout on flutter with code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

class Reporting extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Reporting createState() => _Reporting();
}

class _Reporting extends State<Reporting> {
  SfCartesianChart _getAnimationLineChart() {
    return SfCartesianChart(
      plotAreaBorderWidth: 0,
      primaryXAxis: NumericAxis(majorGridLines: MajorGridLines(width: 0)),
      primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
          majorTickLines: MajorTickLines(color: Colors.transparent),
          axisLine: AxisLine(width: 0),
          minimum: 0,
          maximum: 100),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey.shade100,
        ),
        child: Container(

          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              CustomAppBar(),
              Expanded(

                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListView(
                      primary: false,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        GridView(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          gridDelegate:
                              SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                  childAspectRatio: 6 / 3.5,
                                  crossAxisCount: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                              .size
                                              .width >=
                                          1300
                                      ? 4
                                      : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 700
                                          ? 2
                                          : 1),
                          children: [
                            Card(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                              //margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(80, 60, 80, 60),
                              elevation: 3.0,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 0, 0),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      "Number Of Bugs",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black, fontSize: 30.0),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "Critical, High, Info",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.green[900],
                                          fontSize: 20.0),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Card(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                              elevation: 3.0,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 0, 0),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      "Tile 2",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.blue[900],
                                          fontSize: 30.0),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "Tile 2",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.blue[900],
                                          fontSize: 20.0),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Card(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                              elevation: 3.0,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 0, 0),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      "Tile 3",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.deepOrange[900],
                                          fontSize: 30.0),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "Tile 3",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.deepOrange[900],
                                          fontSize: 20.0),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Card(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                              elevation: 3.0,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 0, 0),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      "Tile 3",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.deepOrange[900],
                                          fontSize: 30.0),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "Tile 3",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.deepOrange[900],
                                          fontSize: 20.0),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        GridView(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                //top: 20.0,
                                left: 90.0,
                                right: 100.0),
                            gridDelegate:
                                SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                    childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                                    crossAxisCount: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                .size
                                                .width >=
                                            1300
                                        ? 2
                                        : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >=
                                                700
                                            ? 2
                                            : 1),
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Card(
                                //margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                //margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(80, 60, 80, 60),
                                elevation: 3.0,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    //mychart2Items("Conversion","0.9M","+19% of target"),
                                    _getAnimationLineChart(),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Card(
                                //margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                elevation: 3.0,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 0, 0),
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        "Tile 2",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.blue[900],
                                            fontSize: 30.0),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        "Tile 2",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.blue[900],
                                            fontSize: 20.0),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Card(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                elevation: 3.0,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 0, 0),
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        "Tile 3",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.deepOrange[900],
                                            fontSize: 30.0),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        "Tile 3",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.deepOrange[900],
                                            fontSize: 20.0),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Card(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                elevation: 3.0,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        "Tile 3",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.deepOrange[900],
                                            fontSize: 30.0),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        "Tile 3",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.deepOrange[900],
                                            fontSize: 20.0),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ])
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm getting an error and it is overflowing. Things that I have tried to make it scrollable are used SingleChildScrollView, added shrinkwrap, added scrollAxisDirection. But nothing seems to work. Can someone guild me on how to solve this problem.

```
A RenderFlex overflowed by 408 pixels on the bottom.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column file:///Users/akramkhan/Documents/cshweb/cshwebapp/lib/pages/Reporting.dart:43:24
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and you could remove a couple of widgets and start with this:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          GridView(),
          GridView(),
        ]),
      ),
    );
```

then you can disable scrolls on the grid views and add more things you need.
Hope this helps. Let me pls know if this solves your issue